# Do tags have "Id" field?

Tags: feature-request, discussion

According to [help](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/help/method?method=tags) page, there is no `"Id"` field.

But I am just wondering if there id `"Id"` field for tags, can we get it through API too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.  Tags don't have an `id` field.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there would be, since tags are uniqued by their name-color combination.